# Page Content Refreshed via Web Socket or AJAX

Tags: spring, google-app-engine, rest, jquery, websocket

I am working on a project which is built on Springs MVC and Google App Engine with Objectify.

The major functionality of this app is: If someone posts something new to the Datastore then it should be auto published to the browsers to which it is connected without refreshing the page content. Basically it is a news like site. The data sent to browser is REST APIs based JSON Data.

For implementing this functionality I thought of using the following ways:

1. **AJAX** : I thought of using AJAX call in every 2-3 minutes to get updated. But this solution doesn't seems to be feasible as there are many datastore read operation due to many AJAX calls from many browsers.
2. **Web Socket** : This concept is pretty new to me. I am not aware of this thing. Some **pusher.com** uses this technology for establishing such connections.

Now I need your suggestions, using which of the two above or I am also open to other solutions.

Comment: WebSocket is definitely faster and more efficient than traditional Ajax, but if you use WebSocket, then you'll probably still need to code an Ajax backup for older browsers that don't support WebSocket.

Comment: sir, can you suggest me some examples using web-sockets. I need this app to be run on mobile browsers so may be I don't need to code the AJAX then.

Comment: Maybe you an use the channel API. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/channel/

Comment: If you're looking to use PHP for the back end, Google's [phpwebsocket](http://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/) is a good start. Note that the code is outdated though, and doesn't actually work. Nevertheless, all the component parts are there and it should get you thinking in the right direction. In addition to the above link, you'll also want to read and become familiar with the latest [WebSocket draft](http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-hybi-thewebsocketprotocol-17) in order to get the latest and most accurate information for how to do the handshake, mask/unmask data, etc., etc.

Answer (score 0):

Google app engine does not support web sockets, however it supports something similiar called the channel api which works on older browsers as well. This may not be feasible depending on how many people you will have connected (channels cost 1c per 100). Channels also have some caveats: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/overview#Caveats

As for using Ajax - if you cache the response in memcache and flush the key every 3 minutes then you won't be doing any data store reads unless a new instance is fired up or the key expires.